# Unable to type in react input

Tags: reactjs

This seems like a common mistake and I have seen a few answers too. However, none of the solutions worked for me. I have created 3 input forms with the few combinations. I am unable to type in any of them. Please see my code below:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const ContactForm1 = () => {
  const [formStatus, setFormStatus] = useState('Submit')
  const [name, setName] = useState('')
  const [name1, setName1] = useState('')
  const [name2, setName2] = useState('')

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    setFormStatus('Submitting...')
    let conFom = {
      name, name1, name2
    }
    console.log(conFom)
  }

  const onNameChange = (event) => {
    setName(event.target.value)
  }
  const onName1Change = (event) => {
    setName1(event.target.value)
  }

  return (
    <div className="container mt-5">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} method="POST">
          <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
            <input id="name" name="name" type="text" className="form-control" value={name} 
                placeholder="Please enter your full name" onChange={onNameChange} />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor="name1">Name1</label>
            <input id="name1" name="name1" type="text" className="form-control" defaultValue={name1} 
                placeholder="Please enter your full name1" onChange={onName1Change} />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor="name2">Name2</label>
            <input id="name2" name="name2" type="text" className="form-control"
                placeholder="Please enter your full name2" />
          </div>
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">{formStatus}</button>
        </form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default ContactForm1
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi Sandeep. Looks like I can type in the form input fields except for `Name 2`. The third label Name2 is missing an `onChange` event. https://codesandbox.io/s/nameless-framework-29pjjg?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this exact code to run in [this CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-violet-vqxpi8?file=/src/App.js), and nothing seems wrong with the code itself...

Try restarting your client.

Comment: Thanks! I had a badly implemented keypress handler in a different module. That was the issue